# Rename columns of newly formed database in R

Tags: r

How do I rename columns DR01 to DR07 of my SUM dataset? As you can see for the SUM dataset I am adding values from my df dataset together with the PV dataset. So, I would like the SUM database columns to be DR01_DR01_PV instead of DR01, DR02_DR02_PV instead of DR02, and so on. This would make it easier for me to understand that a sum was made.

Thank you very much!

Code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-09","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10","2021-07-02","2021-07-02",
                 "2021-07-02","2021-07-03","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Monday",
               "Monday"),
       DTPE = c("Ho","Ho","Ho","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Ho","Ho","","","","",""),
       D1 = c(8,1,9, 3,5,4,7,6,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3,4,3,2,4,8), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,7,3,3,4,5,6,4),
       DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3,4,3,2,4,3),DR03 = c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3,4,3,4,5,4),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3,3,4,5,3,4),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9,3,7,5,3,4,3,4,5,6,2,6,4,3,3,4,5,3,4),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3,3,4,5,3,4),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3,3,4,5,3,4)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))


df<-df %>%
  group_by(date2, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR07) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

df<-data.frame(df)  

x<-subset(df, select = DR01:DR07)
x<-cbind(df, setNames(df$D1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
PV<-select(x, date2,Week, D1, ends_with("PV"))

PV<-PV %>%
  group_by(Week) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
PV
  Week     DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV DR06_PV DR07_PV
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Friday      -1.5       0      -1      -1    -1      -2.5    -2.5
2 Monday       2         5       3       5     5       5       5  
3 Saturday     0         0      -1      -1     3      -1      -1  
4 Thursday     4.5       1       0       3     2.5     4.5     3 

SUM<-df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(date2:Week)) %>%
  left_join(PV %>% rename_with( ~str_remove(., "_PV")) %>% 
              pivot_longer(-Week, values_to = "PV")) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value + PV) %>%
  select(-c(value:PV)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = new_value)

 SUM
 date2      Week        D1  DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05  DR06  DR07
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-04-02 Friday      NA  24.5    19    20    27  27    33.5  35.5
2 2021-04-03 Saturday    NA  22      22    22    22  22    22    22  
3 2021-04-08 Thursday    NA  16.5    13    12    15  13.5  16.5  15  
4 2021-04-09 Friday      NA   6.5     8     7     7   7     5.5   5.5
5 2021-04-10 Friday      NA   8.5     7     6     6   6     4.5   4.5
6 2021-07-01 Thursday    NA  16.5    20    21    18  19.5  16.5  18  
7 2021-07-02 Friday      NA  10.5     9    10    11  11     9.5   9.5
8 2021-07-03 Monday      NA  12      12    12    12  12    12    12
```

Comment: Please read the manual for `rename()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pivot_wider` you can use the `names_glue` parameter to name the columns as you want.

```
...
%>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = new_value, 
                names_glue = '{name}_{name}_PV')
```

Comment: Ronak, any idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340103/enter-a-points-value-on-the-graph